# Use react material raised button for google login

Tags: reactjs, material-design, google-oauth, google-signin

I am using react material component for designing our application.

```
<RaisedButton />
```

RaisedButton is the component available in react material on which you can perform normal operation as you did on normal HTML button.
http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/raised-button

Simultaneously I also used react google login (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-login) which gives its own button to use.

But its designing its so bad thats why I want to use material component. Now, how can I used `RaisedButton` with react-google-login component ?

Any suggestions ?

NOTE : No need to copy css from material and pass to react-google button

Answer (score 2):

You can not swap the component `Button` react-google-login with the `RaisedButton` from material-ui. But what you can do is to use the `style` and `className` props of the google-login and css it to your needs e.g. by copy pasting the style of the `RaisedButton` from the html source.

As a side note imo the design of the google login button is a trademark itself and should not be re-designed. Could generate mistrust towards the user.

Comment: Yes thats true but I made same as google trademark but with extra material design, which gives good look and feel while it use. To copy style its something not good. Need other solution